# plone.formwidget - Is it possible to set a MasterSelect Field as an AutocompleteFieldWidget?

Tags: autocomplete, plone, master-slave

I am trying to set a MasterSelect field to an AutocompleteFieldWidget.
I'm using AutocompleteFieldWidget from plone.formwidget.autocomplete and the MasterSelectField from plone.formwidget.MasterSelect.  The slave field belonging to the MasterSelectField is also a MasterSelectField.

The autocomplete functions as it should (retrieving the values based on input), but the slave field's choices do not change.  However, when its not set as an autocomplete, everything works as it should.

Edit:
In my buildout-cache, I looked at widget.py in plone.formwidget.masterselect and tried placing a print statement in getSlaves and that function wasn't getting called.  I tried the render function and that wasn't getting called either.  Then I placed a print statement in MasterSelectField and that was notgetting called.  Setting the field to an Autocomplete widget removes any trace that its a Master Select field.

Edit: In the **init**.py file in plone.formwidget.masterselect, I placed a print statement in the init function of the MasterSelectField, and the slave widget does print, where as in getSlaves in widget.py it doesn't.  This is the output I'm getting from printing in the init and what I should be getting in getSlaves:

```
({'action': 'vocabulary', 'masterID': 'form-widgets-IMyForm-master_field', 
'control_param': 'master_value', 'name': 'IMyForm.slave_field', 
'vocab_method': <class 'my.product.vocabulary.SlaveVocab'>},)
```

I have my interface:

```
from plone.directives import form


class IMyForm(model.Schema):
    form.widget(master_field=AutocompleteFieldWidget)
    master_field = MasterSelectField(
        title=_(u'Master'),
        slave_fields=({'name':'IMyForm.slave_field',
            'action':'vocabulary',
            'source':MySource,
            'control_param':'master_value'
        }),
        required=True,
    )
    slave_field = MasterSelectField(title=_(u'Slave Field'),
                               source=SlaveVocab,
                               slave_fields=(....
                               )
                               required=False,
                      )
```

I have my source object for the master field:

```
class MySource(object):
    implements(IQuerySource)

    def __init__(self, context):
        simple_terms = []   
        #Query portal catalog for unique indexes, and fill with simple terms
        self.vocab = SimpleVocabulary(simple_terms)

    def __contains__(self, term):
        return self.vocab.__contains__(term)

    def getTermByToken(self, token):
        return self.getTermByToken(token)

    def getTerm(self, value):
        return self.getTerm(value)

    def search(self, query_string):
        return [term for term in self.vocab if query_string in term.title.lower()]

class MySourceBinder(object):
    implements(IContextSourceBinder)

    def __call__(self, context):
        return MySource(context)
```

My slave field's source is:

```
class SlaveVocab(object):
    grok.implements(IContextSourceBinder)

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.master_value = kw.get('master_value', None)

    def __call__(self, context):
        if self.master_value is None or self.master_value == "--NOVALUE--"
            self.master_value = getattr(context,'master_field',None)
            #Still nothing, return empty vocabulary
            if self.master_value is None or self.master_value == '--NOVALUE--':
                return SimpleVocabulary([])
        terms = []
        #If not null, building a simple vocabulary to return
        return SimpleVocabulary(terms)
```

I did a print statement in **call** of the Slave Vocabulary and it was being called, but nothing was being passed in.

I also tried using another widget, ChosenFieldWidget.  I get the same results in that it functions as it should, but the slave field's choices do not change.  Is it possible to set a master select field to an autocomplete?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Also, I'm using Solgema.fullcalendar and the content type extends the IEventBasic behavior, so I don't have access to using my own form class I would've liked to have used since Solgema seems to render its own forms.
Edit:
I am using Plone 4.3

Comment: Does trying an alternative to Solgema.fullcalendar help? such as ftw.calendar?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get that to work.  I install it, and follow the instructions, but I can't get the calendar view to be listed in the display views.  Also, I've been working with Solgema.fullcalendar for a while now too.  Does ftw.calendar allow me to use my own form classes instead of it rendering its own forms?  If so, maybe I could use jquery in place of master select.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know off the top of my head